# Weapon sway - the higher FPS the slower sway?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a weapon sway effect script on my weapon but the higher framerate in the game, the slower/weaker the sway effect is.

this is the code i have in Update():

```
    float tiltX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * tiltAngle;
    float tiltY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * tiltAngle;

    Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(tiltY, tiltX, 0);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, target, Time.deltaTime * smoothComplexity);
```

The way I found out is that I built the project and ran it bot with and without VSync. with VSync, the sway effect was normal but when VSync was off, I could barely see the weapon move.

I know that the higher the framerate, the lower the deltaTime.

Any ideas as to how to make the weapoon sway effect speed/velocity constant no matter what framerate the game is running at?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you obtain `smoothComplexity`?

Comment: @Deadzone That is one of the public values.
I have smoothComplexity set to 3 and tiltAngle to 2.

Comment: What happens if you remove `Time.deltaTime`?

Comment: @Deadzone it will be jittery

Comment: That's really weird `Time.deltaTime` should've fixed the problem.

Comment: @Deadzone oh.. it did.. but I had to make smoothComplexity a 0.03 because at 60 FPS, timeDelta is usually around 0.012

Comment: Is the problem fixed now? :)

Comment: @Deadzone yes.. thanks.. As I said, I tried it before, but forgot to divide it by 100 :D